# How to send website visitor's data to Facebook when Facebook website is blocked for visitors?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, google-datalayer

I intend to put the Facebook pixel code in my website in order to show my visitors advertisement on Instagram (re-targeting). But my website visitors are all from Iran and unfortunately Facebook is blocked/filtered in Iran. So, the pixel script would not load for my visitors. Is there a way to send visitor's data to Facebook? If you know of any way please let me know.
P.S.: Instagram is not Blocked in Iran.

Answer (score 1):

Since FB is blocked for your users, you should create a ***passthourh*** backend for Pixel using Facebook server-side API. ([Here](https://medium.com/@victorfilonenko/setting-up-server-side-api-for-facebook-pixel-491d2bd71f20) is a nice tutorial)

Then on your web pages, you should call your own API with the required info for Pixel.
Afterward, our API on your backend, calls the Facebook server-side API.

Now, how to access FB from your server?

1- Get a VPS outside of your country

2- Get a proxy service and use it on your backend. For a node.js sample, look at [this](https://www.vanamco.com/2014/06/24/proxy-requests-in-node-js/).

Comment: in the tutorial it said, "The website must have Facebook Pixel, which records information about the user in cookies (1st party), installed." / How to record user basic information without pixel script? There is no guidance about that in the Facebook server-side API document.